# How can I find the current RGB colour values used in gnome-terminal?

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal

I'm using the [Regolith](https://regolith-linux.org/) desktop environment and would like to find the current RGB colour values that are being used in my gnome-terminal, as shown in the colour bar of neofetch attached.

I've spent a while digging around in */usr/share/themes/Ayu-Mirage-Dark* and *.config/regolith*, but with no luck.

NB - For background I am trying to find the RGB values as I want to duplicate them on a machine running Manjaro i3 (so need to copy and paste the RGB values into *~/.Xresources*).

[image: Neofetch screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you try the color picker tool in Gimp.

[image]

Comment: There's also [gpick](http://www.gpick.org/) in the repos and it's really light, should they not want to install Gimp just for a color picker.

Comment: Thank you, I had considered this.  But it just seems such a manual way of doing it, considering these values are all encoded somewhere, you presumably simply need to know where to look.  The longer I spent looking though, the more this option seemed like defeat!

Comment: In the end, and after more reading, I used [terminal.sexy](https://terminal.sexy/) to export a *gnometerm* theme which looked pretty close to the above.